# PojoQueryBuilder returning all results on doing exact search

Tags: marklogic

I have JSON file in MarkLogic server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <json type="object" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">
  <com.search.ex.Person type="object">
   <name type="object">
    <com.search.ex.Name type="object">
     <firstName type="string">John</firstName>
     <lastName type="string">Doe</lastName>
    </com.search.ex.Name>
   </name>
   <gender type="string">MALE</gender>
   <age type="number">27</age>
   <birthplace type="string">Albany, NY</birthplace>
   <ssn type="string">123-45-6789</ssn>
  </com.search.ex.Person>
 </json>
```

I am trying to search if record is there with 'birthplace' as 'notpresent', which here its not:

```
PojoRepository<Person, String> repo = client
            .newPojoRepository(Person.class, String.class);
repo.search(qb.value("birthplace", "notpresent"), 1);
```

Here it returns the one record present although birthplace does not match.

In Person.java class age is defined as private String birthplace;..

Whats going wrong here...

Comment: What's the full version number for MarkLogic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Goel, it looks like you're using MarkLogic Server 7.0 (ML7).  I can tell because you're seeing `<json type="object" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">` which is only in ML7 because MarkLogic 8.0 (ML8) stores native JSON.  The PojoQueryBuilder and all of java-client-api version 3.x are only compatible with ML8.  Are you able to try again using ML8?

Comment: i was using ML7, upgraded to 8 and its working .. THANKS